# Who was the leader of Uruk-Hai in the Battle of Helm's Deep?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, orcs

I've searched a lot about this, but couldn't find it. I want to know who's the orc (Uruk-Hai) leader from Battle of Helm's Deep who had no helmet (just armor), climbed on the rock and roared very loud.

Comment: generic cgi orc 2063? :-)

Comment: I think that Orc only appears in the movie, where he is not given a name. If I recall Helm's Deep correctly in the books, there are no Orcs singled out as leaders.

Comment: Bill.  His name is Bill.

Comment: @E.J. Not singled out, no, but there is a mention of “many captains” among the Orcs being killed—so there is at least evidence that there were many lower-level leaders.

Comment: Why are you guys trying to be sarcastic and interesting? I know he wasn't in the book, just looking for the answer because they gave a name to some orcs who are less important than him.

Comment: @Hasan Hadžić: Since the book(s) define Tolkien's universe, if the orc wasn't in the book, then how can you reasonably ask questions about him?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

His name has never been revealed.

As E.J. points out in a comment on the question, in the book there are no identifiable commanders:

> It was now past midnight. The sky was utterly dark, and the stillness of the heavy air foreboded storm. Suddenly the clouds were seared by a blinding flash. Branched lightning smote down upon the eastward hills. For a staring moment the watchers on the walls saw all the space between them and the Dike lit with white light: it was boiling and crawling with black shapes. some squat and broad, some tall and grim, with high helms and sable shields. Hundreds and hundreds more were pouring over the Dike and through the breach. The dark tide flowed up to the walls from cliff to cliff. Thunder rolled in the valley. Rain came lashing down.
>
> Arrows thick as the rain came whistling over the battlements, and fell clinking and glancing on the stones. Some found a mark. The assault on Helm's Deep had begun, but no sound or challenge was heard within; no answering arrows came.
>
> The assailing hosts halted, foiled by the silent menace of rock and wall. Ever and again the lightning tore aside the darkness. Then the Orcs screamed, waving spear and sword, and shooting a cloud of arrows at any that stood revealed upon the battlements; and the men of the Mark amazed looked out, as it seemed to them, upon a great field of dark corn, tossed by a tempest of war, and every ear glinted with barbed light.
>
> <sup><sub>*The Two Towers* Book 3 Chapter 7: "Helm's Deep"</sub></sup>

But this original character is unnamed in the movie, as well. According to [the script](http://www.fempiror.com/otherscripts/LordoftheRings2-TTT.pdf) (PDF link), he's just "Uruk-hai Commander":

> ANGLE ON: The URUK-HAI COMMANDER roars at his troops. They stop their march.
>
> WIDE ON: The two armies stand still opposite each other...each waiting for the other.
>
> ANGLE ON: ARAGORN moves to the edge of the BATTLEMENT.
>
> ANGLE ON: The URUK-HAI stand impatiently, waiting for their orders.
>
> ANGLE ON: GIMLI jumps and strains to see.
>
> GIMLI: What's happening out there?
>
> LEGOLAS: Shall I describe it to you?
>
> He looks at GIMLI with a grin.
>
> LEGOLAS (CONT'D): Or would you like me to fetch you a box?
>
> GIMLI laughs.
>
> WIDE ON: The URUK-HAI COMMANDER roars. The ENTIRE URUK-HAI ARMY begins POUNDS their spears on the ground.
>
> <sup><sub>*The Two Towers* (2002)</sub></sup>

Comment: That guy was supposed to be the commander? I thought that was just the guy who blew the Uruk war horn to signal the charge?

Answer (score 0):

[The Lord of the Rings: The Third Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings:_The_Third_Age) considers him the same Uruk-hai as the one who held Meriadoc and Peregrin captive, **Uglúk**. IIRC it was stated elsewhere on some official source(s) that the Uruk-hai captain was Uglúk but I don't recall where.

Comment: I thought Éomer and co killed all of the orcs in that bunch while M&P escaped.

Comment: @Spencer Me too, until I learned this. I asked a question on how Uglúk could escape https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268314/how-did-ugluk-escape-%c3%89omers-assault

Comment: Note that the article you refer to says it's "a loose adaptation," so it's questionable if this idea actually applies anywhere outside of the game.

Answer (score -1):

The [French Tolkien Wikia](http://fr.jrrtolkien.wikia.com/wiki/Uruk-hai) says his name was Mog

Comment: Does it include any source for this claim?

Comment: Father of Worf.

Answer (score -5):

His name is Mog, the Uruk-Hai Commander at Helm's Deep attack.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You really need to cite your source for this, especially since it duplicates an existing answer that does give a (non-canon) source.  Please read [answer] for help writing good answers.