# How did Uglúk escape Éomer's assault?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

After Lurtz's death, Uglúk became the leader of the Uruk-hai who captured Merry and Pippin. Later on, Grishnákh's troops joined them.

When Éomer's riders attacked the troops, Grishnákh escaped pursuing Merry and Pippin into Fangorn Forest, eventually being killed by Treebeard.

Éomer claimed that all the other Uruk-hai were slain by him and his riders. However, later on in the siege of Helm's Deep, Uglúk was the leader of Saruman's army.

[image: Uglúk at Helm's Deep]

So obviously Éomer was wrong, as Uglúk had escaped. How did he do that? Didn't he dare to fight Éomer's Rohirrim and instead stole himself away from the skirmish?

Comment: The name of the orc leader at Helm's Deep is never revealed: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93393/who-was-the-leader-of-uruk-hai-in-the-battle-of-helms-deep

Answer (score 8):

In the Book  The Two Towers chapter 3 Ugluk gets killed by Éomer, in the movie the same happens but the duel between the two are cut.

The commander at helms deep is a different (unnamed) one (also being portrayed by different actors).

Comment: Can you source it please?

Comment: @IkemNoren well the book is the source for the book, and this site lists it as a other character. https://middle-earthcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_Uruk-hai_chieftain 

In all honesty, i have to ask you why you even think this Uruk-Hai is Ugluk?

Comment: AFAIK it is official that the siege commander is the same Ugluk as the one who held the hobbits captive. And they really look identical. An official source that they're actually two different dudes (contrary to what I mean to know) would be good.

Comment: @IkemNoren Person who makes the claim should present their evidence first.

Comment: @DJClayworth I took it for granted. The only source I can recall is _The Lord of the Rings: The Third Age_. But IIRC some other official source(s) stated it was Ugluk.

Comment: @IkemNoren they are Uruk-Hai, not to sound racist but they all look a like...

Comment: @IkemNoren My advice to you is that when you are in a hole, stop digging. DJ Clayworth is right.